# Read bytes beginning is last delimiter position in binary file with java?

Tags: java, binary, delimiter

I have a more than 2GB binary file with million of chunks (of variable length) separated with sequence bytes 0xE8 and 0x35.
Asking, investigating and trying I was able to get the code below (that I don't know if would be efficient in terms
of execution time). The goal of the code is process each chunk at a time and I'm trying to do this:

1. Store 1024 bytes in "inputBytes" for each for loop
2. Convert to a hexadecimal string the content of "inputBytes"
3. Replace all the "E8F5" with carriage return \r (in order to be able to use scanner.nextLine feature )

Doing those 3 steps, now I can process each chunk in the first 1024 bytes, but to process the 2nd 1024 bytes I need to begin
before last delimiter in previous 1024 bytes since the last chunk of previous 1024 bytes could be incompleted and for that reason I store
last delimiter position with "**hexstr.lastIndexOf("E8F5")**" but I don't know how to store the next 1024 bytes beginning
from last delimiter position. I'm trying with "**input.read(inputBytes,lastPos,1024)**" but I get errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:246)
    at ReadBinaryWithDelimiter.ReadBinaryWithDelimiter.main(ReadBinaryWithDelimiter.java:19)
```

**How can I store 1024 bytes, beginning in last delimiter position for each iteration?**

This is the code I have so far:

```
package ReadBinaryWithDelimiter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class ReadBinaryWithDelimiter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File inputFile = new File("./binary");
        int lastPos = 0; //To store position of last delimiter

        try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(inputFile)) {    
            for(int i=1; i<3; i++){ //Loop to read more than one chunk
                byte inputBytes[] = new byte[1024];
                int readBytes = input.read(inputBytes); // Storing 1024 bytes in "inputBytes"
                //Converting to a string the Hexadecimal content of the variable "inputBytes"
                String hexstr=DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(inputBytes);  

                lastPos=hexstr.lastIndexOf("E8F5")-2; //Storing position of last delimiter
                //Replacing all delimiters in "inputBytes" with \r in order to process each chunk
                String str = hexstr.replaceAll("E8F5", "\r"); 

                //Now process each "line" (chunk) since they are separated with \r
                try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str)) {
                    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                        String line = scanner.nextLine();
                        // process the line
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }  
                }       
            }
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {System.err.println("Couldn't read file: " + ex);} 
        catch (IOException ex) {System.err.println("Error while reading file: " + ex);}                
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure the code you're showing us is the code which is causing that exception?  The one-argument `read` method of InputStream should not be capable of throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException, but the three-argument `read` method can.

Comment: Hi VGR. Yes. It does'nt show errors when I use only "input.read(inputBytes)", but the errors appear when I try to use "input.read(inputBytes,lastPos,1024)". How can I fix this issue to be able to read each chunk at a time? thanks again